# sum NULL or converting NULL to 0 to sum sql db2.iseries

Tags: sql, db2

I am a newbee at SQL and am currently trying to query a DB2.iSeries database, and I am stuck.

This is my code:

```
SELECT IPROD, IDESC, IMRP, NONAV
FROM

(SELECT IPROD, IDESC, IMRP FROM IIM WHERE IBUYC IN (<pln.value>) AND IMRP = 'N') AS IM

INNER JOIN
(SELECT I01PROD FROM INV01P
WHERE I01SUPS = '0'
AND I01SUPP = '0')
AS L1 ON IM.IPROD = L1.I01PROD

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT WPROD, SUM(WOPB-WISS+WADJ+WRCT) AS NONAV FROM IWI
WHERE LEFT(WWHS,1) = '9'
GROUP BY WPROD) AS L2 ON IM.IPROD = L2.WPROD

GROUP BY IPROD, IDESC, IMRP, NONAV
HAVING SUM(NONAV) = 0

ORDER BY IPROD
FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

This is the code that I have which works fine when querying: `HAVING SUM(NONAV) = 0`, but the problem I have is there are products which have `NULL` value, which I also need to pull.

I have tried `IFNULL`, `CASE WHEN` at different points with the query, but it fails.

I know how to have the field output view with 0, but when it comes to having sum, it fails to pull these products.

Could someone please help me to pull NULL and 0 values once the field is summed.

Thanks

Comment: now you just have to optimize the inner selects

Comment: Danny, i don' quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT IPROD, IDESC, IMRP, NONAV
FROM

(SELECT IPROD, IDESC, IMRP FROM IIM WHERE IBUYC IN (<pln.value>) AND IMRP = 'N') AS IM

INNER JOIN
(SELECT I01PROD FROM INV01P
WHERE I01SUPS = '0'
AND I01SUPP = '0')
AS L1 ON IM.IPROD = L1.I01PROD

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT WPROD, SUM(WOPB-WISS+WADJ+WRCT) AS NONAV FROM IWI
WHERE LEFT(WWHS,1) = '9'
GROUP BY WPROD) AS L2 ON IM.IPROD = L2.WPROD

GROUP BY IPROD, IDESC, IMRP, NONAV
HAVING SUM(COALESCE(NONAV,0)) = 0

ORDER BY IPROD
FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY
```